# Error importing scalding in sbt project

Tags: scala, twitter, sbt, scalding

I got this error why importing the scalding sbt in  my project build.sbt(ref:
[How to declare dependency on Scalding in sbt project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24736847/how-to-declare-dependency-on-scalding-in-sbt-project)). Kindly help me out.

```
lazy val scaldingCore = ProjectRef(uri("https://github.com/twitter/scalding.git"), "scalding-core")
lazy val myProject = project in file(".") dependsOn scaldingCore
```

> Error:Error while importing SBT project:
> ...
> [warn] ====
>   public: tried [warn]
>   https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/twitter/scalding-core_2.10/0.16.0-SNAPSHOT/scalding-core_2.10-0.16.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
>   [info] Resolving org.scala-lang#scala-compiler;2.10.4 ... [info]
>   Resolving org.scala-lang#scala-reflect;2.10.4 ... [info] Resolving
>   org.scala-lang#jline;2.10.4 ... [info] Resolving
>   org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.4 ... [warn]
>     :::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::: [warn]   ::
>   UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         :: [warn]
>     :::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::: [warn]   ::
>   com.twitter#scalding-core_2.10;0.16.0-SNAPSHOT: not found [warn]
>     :::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::: [warn]  [warn]   Note:
>   Unresolved dependencies path: [warn]
>         com.twitter:scalding-core_2.10:0.16.0-SNAPSHOT [warn]         +-
>   myproject:myproject_2.10:0.1-SNAPSHOT [trace] Stack trace suppressed:
>   run 'last myProject/*:update' for the full output. [trace] Stack trace
>   suppressed: run 'last myProject/*:ssExtractDependencies' for the full
>   output. [error] (myProject/*:update) sbt.ResolveException: unresolved
>   dependency: com.twitter#scalding-core_2.10;0.16.0-SNAPSHOT: not found
>   [error] (myProject/*:ssExtractDependencies) sbt.ResolveException:
>   unresolved dependency: com.twitter#scalding-core_2.10;0.16.0-SNAPSHOT:
>   not found

Comment: Well it's an unresolved dependency error. You might be missing a resolver for the Scalding project. What does your build.sbt look like?

Comment: Post your `build.sbt` file.

Comment: I'd recommend trying an SBT plugin I wrote to get started: https://github.com/danosipov/sbt-scalding-plugin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scalding [publishes jars on Sonatype Maven Central](http://search.maven.org/#search|ga|1|scalding), so you really shouldn't need to mess with the Git `ProjectRef`. You just need to get your sbt [resolvers](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Resolvers.html) correct so that it can find the jars. Start with this in your `build.sbt`:

```
resolvers ++= Seq(
  Resolver.sonatypeRepo("releases"),
  "Concurrent Maven Repo" at "http://conjars.org/repo"
)
```

Cascading [publishes to the Conjars repository](http://www.cascading.org/downloads/#maven) and not Central, so you most likely need that additional resolver as shown.

Try those initially, and if you're still getting unresolved errors, you may need to add [additional repos that Scalding uses](https://github.com/twitter/scalding/blob/509ec04e6e878f22794891dbb79005174fb40ff3/build.sbt#L72-L80) depending on which artifacts you need to depend on—you probably do *not* need the entire `scalding` uber-artifact, you can likely trim down to `scalding-core`, `scalding-commons`, `scalding-repl`, maybe others depending on the needs of your project.

So to be clear, instead of that `ProjectRef` and `dependsOn scaldingCore`, add the above resolvers and something like this:

```
libraryDependencies ++= {
  val scaldingVersion = "0.16.0-RC6"

  Seq(
    "com.twitter" %% "scalding-core"    % scaldingVersion
  , "com.twitter" %% "scalding-commons" % scaldingVersion
  , "com.twitter" %% "scalding-repl"    % scaldingVersion
  )
}
```

And so on.

Comment: Error:scalac: uncaught exception during compilation: scala.reflect.internal.Types$TypeError
Error:scalac: Error: bad symbolic reference. A signature in SchemedSource.class refers to term mapred
in package org.apache.hadoop which is not available.
It may be completely missing from the current classpath, or the version on
the classpath might be incompatible with the version used when compiling SchemedSource.class.
....

but then,I got the above while testing with the code as follows:

Comment: import com.twitter.scalding._
import com.twitter.scalding.ReplImplicits._
import com.twitter.scalding.ReplImplicitContext._
import cascading.pipe.Pipe

class  product {
    val data = Tsv("/resources/products.tsv")
    data.read

}

Comment: Ah, so `scalding-core` [has a dependency on hadoop-client](https://github.com/twitter/scalding/blob/509ec04e6e878f22794891dbb79005174fb40ff3/build.sbt#L324) with "provided" scope—that means it is needed at compile time but is expected to be present in the runtime environment (i.e. when running in Hadoop jobs). You probably need to add your own similar dependency declaration in your project, e.g. `"org.apache.hadoop" % "hadoop-client" % "2.5.0" % "provided"`.

Comment: Gah, they really need to update the Scalding docs for this. This should be a very common workflow and nearly everything on the web and their wiki seems to be outdated and incomplete… You're going to want to build a "fat jar" for deploying your project—[this](https://github.com/Cascading/scalding-tutorial) is a good start but it's also outdated.

Comment: This is a relatively current example project using SBT, you might be able to adapt from its build configuration: https://github.com/deanwampler/scalding-workshop

Comment: I do not agree less for an update of the sbt due to the multi-dependency conflicts. I have an answer that follows, and  may be someone might see if the conflict can be resolved. This is actually from the scalding github that is given me some dependency errors.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109608/discussion-between-taiwo-o-adetiloye-and-ches).